# user running a process with tasklist and python

Tags: python, windows, tasklist

In windows, with python and tasklist :

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'tasklist'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
lines = []
for line in proc.stdout:
    if 'flac' in line:
        lines.append(line)

for l in lines:
    print [l]
```

I get some informtation about the running process.

How I can get the user owner of any process ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of information from Microsoft's [WMIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command. Start off by running `wmic /OUTPUT:wmic-process-info.txt PROCESS get *` on the command line to get a ton of stuff about processes written to wmic-process-info.txt. Then when you know what you're looking for, slim it down to the columns you want and run in python instead of saving to a file. `wmic PROCESS get a,b,c`.